# Cannot update ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I've just started learning RoR and I've come across a problem.

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

But when I try to install version 1.9.3 this is what happens:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
Already installed ruby-1.9.3-p484.
To reinstall use:

rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p484
```

Sorry if it's a noob question, I've just started learning.
I'm running Elementary OS (Ubuntu based distro)

Comment: run command `rvm list` there you see the installed ruby rvm in your system . to select a rvm from them use command `rvm use '1.9.3-p484'`

Comment: Just a heads up, after Feb 25, 1.9.3 will only receive security patches, and after Feb 25 2015, 1.9.3 will no longer receive patches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby 1.9.3 is already installed. To use it, write

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

To make it the default version, use

```
rvm --default use 1.9.3
```

And to get all your ruby versions installed, use

```
rvm list
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid there is no option to allow login shell in Elementary OS default terminal, therefore I cannot select rubies with rvm use. Is using a third party terminal a good option?

Comment: Doesn't matter, I've just figured it out. I can use bash --login to do that I suppose

Answer (score 3):

Make ruby 1.9.3 default, or even better use ruby 2.1 if you are just starting with Rails 4.2

```
 rvm --default use 1.9.3
```

or better

```
rvm install 2.1
rvm --default use 2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since RVM performs non-standard installs, the new version won't be automatically chosen.
You have to explicitely "enter" the new Ruby environment with
    `rvm use 1.9.3`